# SQL Consultar entre rango de fecha - pero una fecha puede ser NULL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, windows-server-2012

Buen día comunidad.

Necesito hacer una consulta en SQL (Sql Server 2012) para filtrar por un rango de fechas (FechaInicio - FechaTermino).

La tabla es la siguiente:

**DETENCIONES**

```sql
ID
ESTADO
EQUIPO
FECHAINICIO
FECHATERMINO
```

**El Problema,** es que a veces el Campo `FECHATERMINO` puede ser `NULL` que es porque todavía esta **"detenido" hasta la fecha**  según mi lógica de negocios.

```sql
SELECT * FROM DETENCIONES WHERE EQUIPO=1
AND @FECHA >= FECHAINICIO AND @FECHA <= FECHATERMINO
```

Ya probé con un OR pero me devuelve todos los EQUIPOS que tengan un NULL en su fecha de término, es decir no respeta los paréntesis.

```sql
SELECT * FROM DETENCIONES WHERE EQUIPO=@EQUIPO
AND @FECHA >= FECHAINICIO AND (@FECHA <= FECHATERMINO OR FECHATERMINO=NULL)
```

PD: Los datos los visualizo en un Sitio Web creado con ASP.NET C#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lo más sencillo sería usar `ISNULL` con una fecha futura o `GETDATE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Detenciones
WHERE Equipo = 1
AND @Fecha BETWEEN FechaInicio AND ISNULL(FechaTermino,GETDATE());
```

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias!